# Does Update execute for each inheritance for new class C#

Tags: c#, class, oop, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity script that has a `Main` class where all the logic of the games get calculated and executed.

This class has the following structure:

```
public class Main : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private OtherClass OtherGameLogic = new OtherClass(this);        

    private void Update () 
    {
        // all complex frame to frame calculations are done here. 
        // this is gpu and cpu intensive code...
    }
}
```

Now i want to have an other class to take care of some other logic in the game.. This class needs to be initialised in the Main class but also needs to have acces to the Monobehaviour class just like main.
this class looks like this:

```
public class OtherClass
{
    private Main M;

    public OtherClass(Main m)
    {
        M = m;
    }  
    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        m.SomeFunctionThatNeedsMToRun();
    }
}
```

Does this mean that the `Update` Method in Main is called twice? since `OtherClass` takes `Main` as a parameter? Because if that is the case this would be terrible for performance..

I am very new to OOP and C# is general so sorry if the question is a bit weird.
If something is unclear let me know so i can clarify :)

Comment: no, it is not called twice

Comment: so what exactly happens when you do this then? does it only inherit its functions and data? but it doesnt execute them right?

Comment: It won't execute twice because you're not calling `m.Update()` in `OtherClass`. _Something_ needs to call it.

Comment: No, The `Main` that is passed to the constructor of `OtherClass` is just a *reference* to main, it doesn't create a new instance.  It's like one person having 2 phone numbers.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't do any explicit call to it, Update will be called once per frame on each enabled component / monobehaviour of each enabled gameObject in Scene hierarchy.

In your case, you are just doing a reference, not creating a new instance of Main component. So, it won't be called one additional time here.

Answer (score 2):

Passing an object as a parameter into a method is not inheritance.

The `: MonoBehaviour` next to `Main` is specifying that it inherits from `MonoBehaviour`. Nothing is inheriting from `Main`.

If you had `OtherClass : Main` and `OtherClass` had an `Update` method, Unity would call that method to update it **instead** of calling the `Update` method from its parent class.

If you want both to be called, `Main.Update` should be `protected virtual` and `OtherClass.Update` should be `protected override` and also needs to explicitly call `base.Update()`.